# Aplicar dos clases a un mismo texto

Tags: html, css, class

Tengo una duda que supongo sera muy tonta, pero soy bastante novato y llevo buscando 15 minutos por Internet y no encuentro una respuesta, me salen otras cosas.

Como puedo poner dos clases a un mismo texto, tengo por un lado una clase de posicionamiento y por otro lado una clase del formato del texto, me gustaría aplicarle ambas al mismo texto. He probado a poner dos veces la categoría de class, pero el corrector me da un error por que esta dos veces y separandolas con "," tampoco he conseguido que me funcione.

Gracias por la ayuda, aun tengo mucho que aprender.

Comment: Ni lo separes ni repitas nada, simplemente pon una al lado de la otra, separadas por un ESPACIO, no una COMA :) `<p class="izquierda amarillo negrita grande">Este texto estaría a la izquierda, en amarillo, negrita y tamaño grande</p>` El atributo se llama 'class' pero acepta múltiples clases, no tengas miedo en poner las que necesites

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!

Comment: De nada, te dejé en respuestas un ejemplo breve por si acaso :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dejo un pequeño ejemplo de cómo puedes utilizar varias clases que hacen cosas diferentes a la vez

```css
.amarillo {
  color: yellow;
}

.grande {
  font-size: 3em;
}

.derecha {
  float: right;
}

.negrita {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<p>Texto normal</p>
<p class="grande">Texto grande</p>
<p class="grande amarillo">Texto grande y amarillo</p>
<p class="grande amarillo negrita">Texto grande, amarillo y en negrita</p>
<p class="grande amarillo negrita derecha">
  Texto grande, amarillo, en negrita y a la derecha
</p>
```

Comment: Gracias por el trabajo compañero! Da gusto encontrar gente tan amable, asi se hace mas facil aprender.